# How to elegantly filter a java stream repeatedly until a single result is found?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following function which attempts to progressively narrow down an input collection until a single element is found, i.e. filtering is supposed to stop when a single item has been found as applying additional filters may result in no match at all.

```
public List<MyObject> determinePotentialCandidates(List<MyObject> allCandidates) {

        List<MyObject> candidates = allCandidates.stream()
                                                 .filter(this::firstCondition)
                                                 .toList();

        if (candidates.size() > 1) {

            candidates = candidates.stream()
                                   .filter(this::secondCondition)
                                   .toList();

            if (candidates.size() > 1) {

                candidates = candidates.stream()
                                       .filter(this::thirdCondition)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            
            // ... and so on
        }

        logResult(candidates);
        return candidates;
    }
```

As this is becomes harder to read with each additional nesting level, I was wondering if there is a more concise way to write this.

Preferably the method should perform each filtering step at most once (although input size is small and filtering is inexpensive - this could potentially be ok to be performed multiple times for the same input) and contain a single exit point.

Comment: Use a loop. Iterate over a list of filter functions and exit early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put all the conditions into a `List` and loop over it, applying one filter on each iteration until there is only one element left.

```java
List<Predicate<MyObject>> conditions = List.of(this::firstCondition, this::secondCondition, this::thirdCondition /*...*/ );
for(int i = 0; i < conditions.size() && allCandidates.size() > 1; i++)
    allCandidates = allCandidates.stream().filter(conditions.get(i)).toList();
// Note: you may need to check if the list is empty here
return allCandidates;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see some options here:

In both I assume conditions are known before hand. This though keeps solution rigid and not extensible. From your posted example I can not say if you observed in your original solution some SOLID principles like open/close for example.

Options:

1. Apply `filter()` several times, chained.
2. As suggested before use a loop to iterate over a condition list.

For the both cases I would suggest some more adjustments.

Make an abstract class or interface to represent the **condition** as concept. Create another class which will be your **condition provider**, this condition provider will maintain a list on **condition** instances. Condition provider can be initialised later with your conditions via dependency injection or a factory.

Your class, in this case, the client of this provider, will receive the provider injected as dependency (constructor). You class will request the provider all conditions it has to validate. Your class will use this list of conditions in a for loop to filter the collection.

This way you can keep flexible which conditions to use for filtering. And hopefully your code will be a bit more maintainable.

Hope this helped you.